# how to set the primary key when writing a pandas dataframe to a sqlite database table using df.to_sql

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, primary-key

I have created a sqlite database using pandas df.to_sql however accessing it seems considerably slower than just reading in the 500mb csv file.

I need to:

1. set the primary key for each table using the df.to_sql method
2. tell the sqlite database what datatype each of the columns in my
   3.dataframe are? - can I pass a list like [integer,integer,text,text]

code.... (format code button not working)

```
if ext == ".csv": 
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/data/" +filename) 
columns = df.columns columns = [i.replace(' ', '_') for i in columns]

df.columns = columns
df.to_sql(name,con,flavor='sqlite',schema=None,if_exists='replace',index=True,index_label=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None)
```

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately there is no way right now to set a primary key in the pandas df.to_sql() method. Additionally, just to make things more of a pain there is no way to set a primary key on a column in sqlite after a table has been created.

However, a work around at the moment is to create the table in sqlite with the pandas df.to_sql() method. Then you could create a duplicate table and set your primary key followed by copying your data over. Then drop your old table to clean up.

It would be something along the lines of this.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/data/" +filename) 
columns = df.columns columns = [i.replace(' ', '_') for i in columns]

#write the pandas dataframe to a sqlite table
df.columns = columns
df.to_sql(name,con,flavor='sqlite',schema=None,if_exists='replace',index=True,index_label=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None)

#connect to the database
conn = sqlite3.connect('database')
c = conn.curser()

c.executescript('''
    PRAGMA foreign_keys=off;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    ALTER TABLE table RENAME TO old_table;

    /*create a new table with the same column names and types while
    defining a primary key for the desired column*/
    CREATE TABLE new_table (col_1 TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                            col_2 TEXT);

    INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;

    DROP TABLE old_table;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;''')

#close out the connection
c.close()
conn.close()
```

In the past I have done this as I have faced this issue. Just wrapped the whole thing as a function to make it more convenient...

In my limited experience with sqlite I have found that not being able to add a primary key after a table has been created, not being able to perform Update Inserts or UPSERTS, and UPDATE JOIN has caused a lot of frustration and some unconventional workarounds.

Lastly, in the pandas df.to_sql() method there is a a dtype keyword argument that can take a dictionary of column names:types. IE: dtype = {col_1: TEXT}

Answer (score 7):

Building on Chris Guarino's answer, here's some functions that provide a more general solution.  See the example at the bottom for how to use them.

```
import re

def get_create_table_string(tablename, connection):
    sql = """
    select * from sqlite_master where name = "{}" and type = "table"
    """.format(tablename) 
    result = connection.execute(sql)

    create_table_string = result.fetchmany()[0][4]
    return create_table_string

def add_pk_to_create_table_string(create_table_string, colname):
    regex = "(\n.+{}[^,]+)(,)".format(colname)
    return re.sub(regex, "\\1 PRIMARY KEY,",  create_table_string, count=1)

def add_pk_to_sqlite_table(tablename, index_column, connection):
    cts = get_create_table_string(tablename, connection)
    cts = add_pk_to_create_table_string(cts, index_column)
    template = """
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        ALTER TABLE {tablename} RENAME TO {tablename}_old_;

        {cts};

        INSERT INTO {tablename} SELECT * FROM {tablename}_old_;

        DROP TABLE {tablename}_old_;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    """

    create_and_drop_sql = template.format(tablename = tablename, cts = cts)
    connection.executescript(create_and_drop_sql)

# Example:

# import pandas as pd 
# import sqlite3

# df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": [2,3,4]})
# con = sqlite3.connect("deleteme.db")
# df.to_sql("df", con, if_exists="replace")

# add_pk_to_sqlite_table("df", "index", con)
# r = con.execute("select sql from sqlite_master where name = 'df' and type = 'table'")
# print(r.fetchone()[0])
```

There is a gist of this code [here](https://gist.github.com/RobinL/c27fef037cbd2b24c909d5275b01adfb)

Answer (score 7):

In pandas version 0.15, `to_sql()` got an argument `dtype`, which can be used to set both dtype and the primary key attribute for all columns:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'MyID': [1, 2, 3], 'Data': [3, 2, 6]})
with sqlite3.connect('foo.db') as con:
    df.to_sql('df', con=con, dtype={'MyID': 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY',
                                    'Data': 'FLOAT'})
```

Comment: This would be a really nice solution, but it does not work for me.
What package are you referring to that should have version 0.15?
My pandas is at 1.4.2; sqlalchemy at 1.4.36; sqlite at 3.38.5.
I'm trying to write to a postgres database.

Comment: This solution is for SQLite via python's sqlite3 API (`flavor='sqlite'`). It may not work for other SQL variants.

Comment: @yellowdolphin thanks for that. Just leaving the reference for later use: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Answer (score 2):

Building on Chris Guarino's answer, it is almost impossible to assign a Primary key to an already existing column using df.to_sql() method. Likewise in your 500mb csv file you cannot create an duplicate table with huge number of columns.

However a small Workaround of addding a new column as Primary key while creation of dataframe to SQL. It is possible to iterate over Pandas **dataframe.columns** function to create a new database and while the creation you can add a Primary key. With this duplicate table is not needed.

i am adding a small Code snippet of it.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import sqlalchemy 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df= pd.read_excel(r'C:\XXX\XXX\XXXX\XXX.xlsx',sep=';')
X1 = df1.iloc[0:,0:]
dataset = X1.astype('float32')
dataset['date'] = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', periods=len(dataset), freq='D')
dataset=dataset.set_index('date')

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///measurement.db')

sqlite_connection = engine.connect()

sqlite_table = "table1"
sqlite_connection.execute("CREATE TABLE table1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  date TIMESTAMP, " +
         ",".join(["%s REAL" % x for x in dataset.columns]) + ")" )
dataset.to_sql(sqlite_table, sqlite_connection, if_exists='append')

Output database table:
[(0, 'id', 'INTEGER', 0, None, 1),
(1, 'date', 'TIMESTAMP', 0, None, 0),
(2, 'time_stamp', 'REAL', 0, None, 0),
(3, 'column_1', 'REAL', 0, None, 0),
(4, 'column_2', 'REAL', 0, None, 0)]
```

This method works only if the **dataframe has an index.** Also to have the index as column in our table it should be explicitly defined while writing our query.

Hope this helps for huge database creations.

Answer (score 1):

In Sqlite, with a normal rowid table, unless the primary key is a single `INTEGER` column (See [ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) in the documentation), it's equivalent to a `UNIQUE` index (Because the real PK of a normal table is the `rowid`).

Notes from [the documentation for rowid tables](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html):

> The PRIMARY KEY of a rowid table (if there is one) is usually not the true primary key for the table, in the sense that it is not the unique key used by the underlying B-tree storage engine. The exception to this rule is when the rowid table declares an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. In the exception, the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY becomes an alias for the rowid.
>
> The true primary key for a rowid table (the value that is used as the key to look up rows in the underlying B-tree storage engine) is the rowid.
>
> The PRIMARY KEY constraint for a rowid table (as long as it is not the true primary key or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) is really the same thing as a UNIQUE constraint. Because it is not a true primary key, columns of the PRIMARY KEY are allowed to be NULL, in violation of all SQL standards.

So you can easily fake a primary key after creating the table with:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mytable_fake_pk ON mytable(pk_column)
```

Besides the `NULL` thing, you won't get the benefits of an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` if your column is supposed to hold integers, like taking up less space and auto-generating values on insert if left out, but it'll otherwise work for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option for getting pandas to create a primary key on table creation using some undocumented methods from the pandas internals (at your own risk). You can peruse the code [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.1/pandas/io/sql.py). The key is the `keys` param of `SQLTable` which is not exposed in the `to_sql` API.

Note that I `reset_index` and set `index=False` in the call to `SQLTable` to prevent a [duplicate/unnecessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3379316/10682164) index from being created in addition to the primary key constraint.

```py
from pandas.io.sql import SQLTable, pandasSQL_builder

df = <your dataframe>
engine = <sqlalchemy engine>

table = SQLTable(
    "my_table",
    pandasSQL_builder(engine, schema="my_schema"),
    frame=df.reset_index(),
    index=False,
    keys=df.index.names,
    if_exists=if_exists,
    schema="my_schema",
)

table.create() # Will honor your if_exists settings
table.insert(chunksize, method="multi") # This hits limits in allowed sqlite params if chunks are too large
```

There is also a `get_schema` function in that file that can get you a create table statement if you want to do something manually.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that. You can only set the primary key directly in the database after you move the data.