# Android room composite primary key, sort order

Tags: android, android-room, composite-primary-key

In order to migrate old db to room library, I have to make equivalent to line

```
primary key(id1, id2 desc)
```

from

```
create table t(
id1 integer not null, 
id2 integer not null,
.... 
primary key(id1, id2 desc)
)
```

I can't find how to define sorting order of composite indices or primary keys. It seems like Android room haven't particular annotations, or Annotation parameters if see **androidx.room.Entity** or **androidx.room.Index**.

Is it not supported? What are other ways to solve the problem? Create regular composite key on **id1** and **id2**, and in all **select** queries set **order by** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Room supports raw queries via `RoomDatabase.Callback` so you can override `onCreate` method of callback and execute raw sql of creating index.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your table is `WITHOUT ROWID`, the primary key in your table is just a separate unique index.

So you just have to create your own index after the table is created.

[Is an index needed for a primary key in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379292/is-an-index-needed-for-a-primary-key-in-sqlite)

Look at the sqlite3 example - sqlite just creates a separate `sqlite_autoindex_t_with_pk_1` for you along with manually created indices.

```
sqlite> create table t_with_pk(id1 integer not null, id2 integer not null, primary key(id1, id2 desc));

sqlite> create table t_no_pk(id1 integer not null, id2 integer not null);    
sqlite> create unique index t_uniq_idx on t_no_pk(id1, id2 desc);

sqlite> select * from sqlite_master;

table|t_with_pk|t_with_pk|2|CREATE TABLE t_with_pk(id1 integer not null, id2 integer not null, primary key(id1, id2 desc))
index|sqlite_autoindex_t_with_pk_1|t_with_pk|3|
table|t_no_pk|t_no_pk|4|CREATE TABLE t_no_pk(id1 integer not null, id2 integer not null)
index|t_uniq_idx|t_no_pk|5|CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t_uniq_idx on t_no_pk(id1, id2 desc)
```

The behavior is also identical

```
sqlite> explain query plan select * from t_with_pk order by id1, id2 desc;
QUERY PLAN
`--SCAN TABLE t_with_pk USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_t_with_pk_1
sqlite> explain query plan select * from t_no_pk order by id1, id2 desc;
QUERY PLAN
`--SCAN TABLE t_no_pk USING COVERING INDEX t_uniq_idx
```

Note also (regarding @Developer's answer) that just inverting the order in a `SELECT` statements requires sqlite to create a temp index

```
sqlite> explain query plan select * from t_no_pk order by id1, id2;
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN TABLE t_no_pk USING COVERING INDEX t_uniq_idx
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR RIGHT PART OF ORDER BY
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do somehow like

SELECT
select_list
FROM
table
ORDER BY
column_1 ASC,
column_2 DESC;

for details https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-order-by/

Comment: sorry, I should specified that I need to do it by Android.Room first, but yeah, thanks, I thought about extends sql queries by **order by**

Comment: You can get idea from here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297165/room-dao-order-by-asc-or-desc-variable